# Scheduled Job Membership renewal reminder not running

Tags: joomla, scheduled-reminders

Schedule Job for mailings is not working correctly. Other scheduled jobs are working - membership status updates, smart group updates,etc. There should be 250+ renewal emails sent to members with expire date of 12/31/2019, but nothing is sent out. Server will restrict to 50 emails at a time, but should send in tranches of 50. I tried manual execution of scheduled jobs and get same response. We're running Civicrm 5.1.14 with Joomla 3.9.15 on PhP 7.2. Any thoughts? I didn't find any recent examples of this error on stackexchange.

Based on work done by a third party Civicrm partner firm, we have two cron jobs:

```
 /usr/local/bin/php /home/jgsny/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s jgsny.org -u civicrm -p xxxxxx -e Job -a execute
```

AND

```
/usr/bin/wget -O - -v -t 2 'https://jgsny.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=civicrm&pass=xxxxxxx&key=xxxxxxx'
```

The cron job sends a single message:

```
--2019-12-02 12:55:01--  https://jgsny.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=civicrm&pass=xxxxxx&key=xxxxxxx
Resolving jgsny.org (jgsny.org)... 209.124.74.61
Connecting to jgsny.org (jgsny.org)|209.124.74.61|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 0 [text/html]
Saving to: 'STDOUT'

     0K                                                        0.00 =0s

2019-12-02 12:55:02 (0.00 B/s) - written to stdout [0/0]
```

Comment: What version of civicrm? And have you checked for errors in your Civicrm Config and log. -> https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer provides a nice way to view this - otherwise it will be located in the Civicrm Files directory under ConfigAndLog

Answer (score 1):

The cron job `Job.execute` is running all active cron task defined in menu Administer -> System settings -> Scheduled Jobs

If your cron is running as it seems to be, you might first want to check :

- if the task `Send Scheduled Reminders` is enabled in  Administer -> System settings -> Scheduled Jobs
- if the frequency is correct - it should be daily or hourly maybe
- when you click View Job Log - do you have any error

Comment: Scheduled reminder task is activ as is frequency. Log shows the following:

Comment: Scheduled reminder task is active as is frequency. To troubleshoot, I temporarily set to development environment, but now is changed back to production. Log shows the following

Date Job Name Command/Job Status/Additional Information
2019-12-04 00:01:04 Send Scheduled Reminders 
Entity: Job Action: send_reminder
Summary
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Success (1)
Details
Not getting cron error email from server.

Comment: Keep in mind that the reminders task is sending only if the condition is valid on the day it is ran. So if the task failed or the cron was not ran on the renewal day, it won't do any catching-up.